# Dynamically Change image source destination Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to change user profile image for different user.
I  used following code for add image source

```
 <img src="{{ asset('bundles/dist/img/user4-128x128.jpg') }}" alt="User Image" class="img-circle" />
```

All images are saved as username in bundles/dist/img/ directory

i try change  image source following manner

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/dist/img/ '~{{ app.user.username }}~'.jpg') }}" alt="User Image" class="img-circle" />
```

But it is not working ?
What is the best way doing this ?

Comment: the images are uploaded by the users or are with your bundle asset? If the second, have you launch the command `asset:install` from the shell? have you tried to display the images in the browser with the url?

Comment: image is already uploaded i want  change source destination dyamically

Comment: are the `~` in the image filename? You need the tilde to concat only inside a twig statement

Comment: i try that symbol for concat string

Comment: but it is not working

Comment: ah sorry try without the doble brace in the username as `asset('bundles/dist/img/ '~ app.user.username ~'.jpg')`

Comment: yes . I tried  .but not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly right, what should work is this:

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/dist/img/'~ app.user.username ~'.jpg') }}" alt="User Image" class="img-circle" />
```

you need to remove the brackets inside, because you already opened them before calling the asset function therefore the variable is already available in this context